# Writing custom events class in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a generic custom Event class in C++. The event handler is a class member function. So, I've used a map to store the object and the event handler function pointer. Below is my class definition.

```
class EventArgs
{
public:
    void* m_object; 
public:
    EventArgs(void* obj)
    {
        m_object = obj;
    }
};

// templated function pointer that can point to any class member function 
// which takes in a EventArgs* and returns void
template<typename T>
struct TFunctr
{
     void (T::*EventHandler)(EventArgs* ev);
};

template<typename T>
class Event
{
protected:
    map<T,TFunctr<T>::EventHandler> m_eventHandlers; // store the member function pointer along with the object.

    void addListener(T object, TFunctr<T> handler)
    {
        m_eventHandlers[object] = handler;
    }

    void removeListener(T object, TFunctr<T> handler)
    {       
        m_eventHandlers.erase(object);
    }

    virtual void fire(EventArgs* ev)
    {
        // ensure that there are subscribers(listeners) for this event
        if(!m_eventHandlers.empty())
        {
            for(map<T, TFunctr<T>>::iterator iter = m_eventHandlers.begin(); iter != m_eventHandlers.end(); ++iter)
            {
                T obj = iter->first;                    // get the object
                TFunctr<T>::EventHandler hnd = (TFunctr<T>::EventHandler) iter->second; // get the member function ptr

                (obj.*hnd)(ev); // invoke the function
            }
        }
    }

    virtual ~Event()
    {
        // clear the eventhandlers list
        m_eventHandlers.clear();        
    }
};
```

I'm getting a compilation error at line 25:

***error C2923: 'std::map' : 'TFunctr::EventHandler' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'***

Appreciate your help in fixing these.

I can't upgrade to C++11 as the code is targeted for g++ 4.1.2.
I have read about the boost libraries (signal and slot) but I wanted to keep it as a last resort.

(I've been working in C# and recently moved to a project which is in C++. So, I'm having difficulty in understanding the C++ syntax and semantics.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When asking about a compilation error: **1.** Post the complete & unedited error message (unless it's pages of nested template errors, in which case post the first few and the last few), **2.** Indicate on which source line exactly the error occurs. If that line is a complex expression, break it down into several statements, compile again and then post it here.

Comment: Come on. You get compilation errors so why not include them in the question. You expect everyone to just guess the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry I missed to post the error. I've updated my question with exact error message and I can't use C++11 as it is targeted for g++ 4.1.2. Can you please suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer for your compilation errors, since you've not posted them, but if you've got access to C++11 then you could use the [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) class to simplify dealing with the callbacks/listeners:

```
class EventArgs
{
public:
    void* m_object; 
public:
    EventArgs(void* obj)
    {
        m_object = obj;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Event
{
  std::vector<std::function<void(T&)> m_EventHandlers;

public:

  void addListener(std::function<void(T&)> handler)
  {
    m_EventHandlers.push_back(handler)
  }

  void removeListener(std::function<void(T&)> handler)
  {
    // etc etc
  }

  virtual void fire(EventArg &args)
  {
    for(auto handler : m_EventHandlers)
    {
      handler(args);
    }
  }
};
```

Now you can say:

```
Event event;
event.addListener([](Event &e){std::cout << "got an event";})
```

NOTE: I've changed the event argument to a reference to indicate that there's always and event object. If it's valid for there not to be (which seems unlikely) then turn it back to a pointer. I've left it as non-const to allow the handlers to modify the data in the event, which is more in line with how C# events work.

Comment: +1.  You might also want to suggest turning those `T*` in to `const T&` :)

Comment: I've updated my question with exact error message and I can't use C++11 as it is targeted for g++ 4.1.2. Can you please suggest? Thanks.